# Starting couchdb from node.js via exec or spawn

Tags: node.js, unix, couchdb

I'm attempting to start couchdb from node.js if it hasn't already been started. Code like the following works for basic commands like `pwd` but not for `couchdb`:

```
var sys = require('util')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

// executes `pwd`
child = exec("pwd", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
  sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

I've tried using '`couchdb`' & '`/usr/local/bin/couchdb`' as arguments to exec.

Comment: Sharing you think it's a bad idea without qualification isn't valuable to anyone—I don't know what the smily face is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a working example now using CoffeeScript:

```
childproc = require "child_process"    
couchdb = childproc.spawn "couchdb"
couchdb.stdout.setEncoding "utf8"
buffer = ""

couchdb.stdout.on "data", (data) ->
  lines = (buffer + data).split(/\r?\n/)
  buffer = lines.pop()
  lines.forEach (line, index) ->
    console.log line

couchdb.stdout.on "end", ->
  if buffer.length > 0
      console.log buffer
      buffer = ""
    console.log 'process ended'
```

[See my gist for a fuller example in CS, Iced CS & JS](https://gist.github.com/733e4de4b328f4fd88dc)

**EDIT**
Here is the ouput in Javascript:

```
var buffer, childproc, couchdb;

childproc = require("child_process");

couchdb = childproc.spawn("couchdb");

couchdb.stdout.setEncoding("utf8");

buffer = "";

couchdb.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
  var lines;
  lines = (buffer + data).split(/\r?\n/);
  buffer = lines.pop();
  return lines.forEach(function(line, index) {
    return console.log(line);
  });
});

couchdb.stdout.on("end", function() {
  if (buffer.length > 0) {
    console.log(buffer);
    buffer = "";
  }
return console.log('process ended');
});
```

Comment: any chance you could post the JS output - equivalent?

Comment: @ClintNash I am happy to, but have noticed that Marcus has been nice enough to do that for us. I can provide you with a fuller example, where I test whether couch is running, turn it on if necessary, then test if a db exists and create if not. https://gist.github.com/733e4de4b328f4fd88dc

Comment: +1 Yes, please. Maybe just jsFiddle it? Entries like this can be valuable to cross-trainers on node.js, and to those couchdb noobs~like-me. #value-add. Yourock @Cirrostratus, Thanks.

Comment: @ClintNash I did post it—look @ the end of that comment.